# Android Custom loader issue

Tags: android, ui-thread

I launch an IntentService in my activity and I want to show a "custom loader" during the treatment of this IntentService.

This "custom loader" is an imageview, that I want to show and hide every 100 MS.

I wrote this, but it doesn't work, the UI Thread is blocked :

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!taskDone) {
                        LogUtils.log("run " + taskDone);
                        try {
                            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

I call this code in the "onResume" method.
The variable "taskDone" becomes "true" when the IntentService is done. (This works.)

With this code I've two problems :

- The UI Thread seems "blocked"
- It seems the background thread didn't success to see "taskDone" has a different value after few seconds.

Comment: You realize you're running that `while` loop with its `Thread.sleep()` calls on the UI thread, yeah?

Comment: It solves nothing to delete it. The UI thread still blocked.

Comment: If you remove that `while` loop completely, and your UI thread is still blocking, then you've got problems elsewhere, too, 'cause that thread you're creating there will then end immediately after starting it.

Comment: If I remove the "while", of course there isn't problem. But I need a loop for my "loader". (And I want to do this treatment in the background for don't have problems with the main UI THREAD, but it doesn't work.)

Comment: Well, then I don't know what you were deleting, but anyway, there are better options for what you're trying to do; like animation, for instance, or just delayed-posting a `Runnable` to the `View` to toggle its visibility, instead of having to mess with another thread.